# How to control abbr tag timing?

Tags: html, css, abbr

How to control abbr tag so that I can not only change the title but also the time, when the message in the title appears? Do I need to use php or js to do so?

Comment: You can not influence when the `title` tooltip is displayed. Use a custom tooltip solution instead – should be easy enough to find resources for that.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna use something like this

```css
abbr {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  bottom:-20px;
  left:0;
  transition:0.5s opacity;
  /* Here is the delay */
  transition-delay:0.5s;
}
.text {
  position:relative;
  cursor:help;
}
.text:hover abbr {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<span class="text"> This is a text with abbrevation <abbr>This is the abbrevation</abbr></span>
```